# WordPress implement custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

**The situation**

A customer has a website made in WordPress for selling houses. When designing the website they made a 'te-koop' (for-sale) post type with dummy items for testing.

So now in the sidebar (backend) I see this:

[Post type in sidemenu in backoffice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gEWP.png)

On the front the main page uses /themes/THEMENAME/archive-te-koop.php
and the detail pages are using /themes/THEMENAME/single-te-koop.php

This all worked fine and I understand how this works.

But now I have to implement data from an API that contains all different houses etc. I can use a custom plugin that generates the shortcodes I need. I have already installed and activated it and used the shortcodes on the homepage.

So then I started editing the archive-te-koop.php file and used do_shortcode() to call the overview of all houses, which works perfectly. And I can surf to using the link: https://DOMAINNAME/te-koop

**The problem**

I now want to edit the single-te-koop.php page for the details of the houses. The problem is that I can only go the detailpages of the dummy items because of the %post-name% being used. (https://DOMAIN/te-koop/%post-name%)

How can I make this work so I can remove the dummy items and then call the API shortcodes in the single-te-koop.php file?

I think the problem is the is_singular() function which results in false if there is not an item in de backoffice.

I really hope someone can help me on my way

Comment: I would migrate the data instead of generating it using shortcodes.

Comment: Hi @RonvanderHeijden, I understand what you mean, I have allready a few CRONjobs i can use to fill up the database. I'm gonna search for a way to do this. Do you know a tutorial or something?